# If I file an amendment to my taxes, do I pay the difference or just the base amount?

Tags: united-states, form-1040x, schedule-k-1

I filed a 1040 a few weeks ago and, per that form, was due a refund. I put in the routing information for my bank information to receive the refund deposit, but I haven't received it yet.

I just received a K-1 and am filing an amendment to my return, a 1040X. Now, per the 1040X, I owe the government money. Do I write them a check for the amount I owe plus the original refund? Or just the amount I owe?

To use fake concrete numbers, let's say my original refund was $1000 and now, per the amendment, I owe $1500. Do I write a check for $2500 or $1500? I have not yet received the refund, but it could be sent before my amended return is processed. Since it's an electronic refund I can't just not cash the check.

Comment: Was your original return accepted and the refund is pending?

Comment: It hasn't been returned with amendments, if that's what you mean. Or at least that's what has happened in the past when there were errors (I forgot to sign it once) or they disagreed with my math. It's also only been two weeks.

Comment: Potential duplicate:  https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/78968/i-need-to-amend-my-return-but-i-already-received-check-from-irs-with-my-refund/78971#78971

Comment: So I should assume that the refund has been paid out or will be paid out? If I had already received the money I wouldn't be confused and I'd just pay the refund amount plus the amount I owe. But I haven't been paid the refund (yet).

Comment: You might want to check refund status to confirm your return was accepted, but you should typically treat it as if the refund has been paid out. However, per the answer on that similar question, the calculation on the 1040x takes into account original refund/amount owed.   https://www.irs.gov/refunds

Comment: There is no status shown on that site. I did file a paper return so that might be slowing things down. I'll cut a check for the value on Line 20 of the 1040X, then.

Comment: Yeah, worst case in that situation is they don't accept the initial return, don't issue the refund, then you've over-paid before the deadline and are owed a refund after that.